# Delete order by using order id

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

How to delete order in magento from order id **100000050** to **100000080** by using MySQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Below the Code use to Delete order from order id 100000050 to 100000080:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$delete = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$order_table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_grid');
$invoice_table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_invoice_grid');
$shipment_table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_grid');
$creditmemo_table = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_creditmemo_grid');

for($orderId = 100000050;$orderId <= 100000080;$orderId++){
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
  if ($order->getId()) {
    $order->delete();
    $sql = "DELETE FROM  " . $order_table . " WHERE entity_id = '" . $orderId . "';";
    $delete->query($sql);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM  " . $invoice_table . " WHERE order_id = '" . $orderId . "';";
    $delete->query($sql);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM  " . $shipment_table . " WHERE order_id = '" . $orderId . "';";
    $delete->query($sql);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM  " . $creditmemo_table . " WHERE order_id = '" . $orderId . "';";
    $delete->query($sql);
  }
}
?>
```